# VPN client cannot access network behind VPN server(wireguard)

Tags: linux, vpn, routing, iptables, wireguard

I have created a wireguard VPN server, but the clients cannot access some networks behind the server,

```
wireguard-server
eno1: 10.10.10.2/24 (GW)
eno2: 10.10.11.2/24
wg0: 10.66.66.1/24
```

I want the client of wireguard VPN can access to network 10.10.11.0/24 (it works with 10.10.10.2/24).

route -n

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.10.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
10.10.11.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno2
10.66.66.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0
```

iptable -S

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 44021 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eno1 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
```

I tried with ip route and masquerade iptable but it didn't work, Please.

**Solved!**

Solved by adding this lines in wg0.conf:

```
     PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eno2 -j MASQUERADE
     PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eno2 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Does [this solution](https://serverfault.com/a/1103038/18736) work for you?

Comment: It's work!  Thank you! very much! Harry!

Comment: @Arthurency hello, answers should be posted below questions, not in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post
[Can't reach networks behind Wireguard VPN server. Split-tunneligt config on client](https://serverfault.com/questions/1102938/cant-reach-networks-behind-wireguard-vpn-server-split-tunneligt-config-on-clie/1103038#1103038)
has this answer :

> Solution was quiet simple.
>
> There is no need of any scripts to get split-tunneling.
>
> **1. Add this lines in wg0.conf:**
>
> ```
>   PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
>   PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
> ```
>
> **2. Modify clients WG config in this way:**
>
> ```
>  [Peer] AllowedIPs = 192.168.99.0/24, 192.168.30.0/24
> ```
>
> **3. Enable `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` on WG server.**
>
> So, I got no routes to internet through WG server, only for that
> specified networks.
>
> Here is more details:
> https://iliasa.eu/wireguard-how-to-access-a-peers-local-network/

Item 1 was enough to solve the poster's problem.